# drupal exposed filter with jquery datepicker popup

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a view that I created based upon a content type in my drupal instance.  I have then went and added some exposed filters.  Two of these filters are date fields that use the jquery ui datepicker popup.  Functionally, everything is working fine.  Aesthetically, everything is not fine....

With the date picker, The label is showing up in the correct place, but the actual text box where the date will ultimately display is dropped down to the next line.  Has anyone worked with this module that might be able to give me an idea of where the issue might be?  If I just put a regular exposed filter on (that works with regular text fields instead of dates), it works fine.

This leads me to believe it is something to do with the module css, but I don't know where else to look.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem might actually be in your theme. There might be a class definition that's overruling the module's definitions and throwing the layout off.

If you switch your page to Garland and the problem goes away, then you'll know you need to look in your theme to find the offending element. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and similar tools will help you find that quickly.

The default CSS in that whole suite of Date-related modules is pretty robust, in my experience. I've thrown them into some pretty hairy page layouts and they've always performed admirably, so the module's CSS is probably the last place I'd look for a problem.

Comment: I will try changing to a default theme and see what that does.  I have used firebug, but have not been able to isolate the offending style.  Perhaps by using a default theme, I will be able to find it.
Thanks